# Getting a child element with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium

I have this HTML:

```html
<div id = "d029384">
<span>......</span>
</div>
```

and my code:

```
elem = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@id,'d')]")
```

except the div isn't working for what my program is doing. I need to be more specific. I need the span element instead. How can I get the span element?
Each div has an id that is d + numbers. I need those numbers so that's why I used that xpath but I don't know how to make the final WebElement point to the span and not to the div.

Anyone know?

Comment: that is an ugly xpath.. that means if I have, later down the road, `<div id="desert_storm"><span id="movie">` your test will fail.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you finding the right `div`? If so, to get the `span` inside that `div`, just add `/span`:

```
elem = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@id,'d')]/span")
```

Comment: I thought you might be able to do that but I wasn't sure which element it would return (div or span). Thanks.

Comment: With XPath, things inside `[...]` means "such that" -- sort of like a modifying clause. The parts of the path separated by `/` indicate the main path. The final element specified in the main path is the type of element ultimately returned.

Comment: @unutbu This works fine if we know the id or single `div` whose id is `d`. But in case multiple div has same class and we want to get child element of each `div` separately??

Answer (score 9):

Or without using xpath, you can do (in case you have a single span in the div):

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_id("d029384").find_element_by_tag_name("span")
```